# Right way to check whether a user subscribed?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I'm querying subscription status with following code. With this I'm able to get boolean status about this subscription. Will this result affected by network status or package uninstall/reinstall or any other criteria. Is the right to way to find the subscription status ?

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, PUBLIC_KEY);
mHelper.startSetup( new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        if ( ! result.isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }
        if (QueryInventoryListner.mHelper == null){
            return;
        }
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });
```

& Query Inventory Finish Listner

```
mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
@Override
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(final IabResult result, final Inventory inventory) {
    Purchase subscriptionForFullVersion = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_SUBSCRIPTION);
    boolean isSubscribe = subscriptionForFullVersion != null ;
        if( isSubscribe ) {
        //User is subscribed to SKU_SUBSCRIPTION
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example of code works even after reinstalling an application.

You forget to add `try\catch` block:

```
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {    
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
           return;
        }
        if (QueryInventoryListner.mHelper == null){
           return;
        }
        try {
           mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        } catch (IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
           complain(context.getResources().getString(R.string.subscription_error_subscription_error_to_query_inventory_another_async));
        }
    }
```

and my mGotInventoryListener like this:

```
// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
private QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Logging.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            complain(context.getResources().getString(R.string.subscription_error_subscription_error_to_query_inventory) + " " + result);
            return;
        }

        Logging.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        // First find out which subscription is auto renewing
        Purchase subscriptionMonthly = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_SUBSRIPTION_MONTHLY);

        // The user is subscribed if either subscription exists, even if neither is auto
        // renewing
        mSubscribedToFreeAds = (subscriptionMonthly != null);
        Logging.d(TAG, "User " + (mSubscribedToFreeAds ? "HAS" : "DOES NOT HAVE")
                + " monthly subscription.");
        if (mSubscribedToFreeAds) {
            putPurchase(subscriptionMonthly);//save purchase
            isSubscribed = true;
        } else {
            clearPurchase();
            isSubscribed = false;
        }

        updateUi();
        setWaitScreen(false);
        Logging.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

Also you can test your subscription before release:
[Setting Up for Test Purchases](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test)